# Make jquery code only apply on a certain range of viewport aspect ratio

Tags: jquery

My site currently has two css configurations. One for normal computers, and one for phones. This is accomplished by using `@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 12/9)` for landscape devices and `@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 12/9)` for portrait.

I have written some jQuery code that I want to only apply when the viewport is in the `min-aspect-ratio range of 12/9` (aka wide-screen).

I tried to do this by wrapping all the code (except `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` ) in 
`if $('window').math(width()/height()) => 1.33` (width divided by height is larger than 1.33), but I probably wrote it wrong. I'm a newbie when it comes to jQuery so my mistakes are probably elementary.

Comment: `if (($('window').width()/$('window').height()) >= 1.33)`

Comment: syntaxError: Unexpected idenftifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following `if` statement:

```
if ((window.screen.width / window.screen.height) >= 1.33)
```

`$(window).width()`  and `height()` provides current window size, not total screen size so it isn't same as your CSS media queries.